# Internet Explorer 11 css style of range slider

Tags: css, slider, range, internet-explorer-11

I would like to style range slider with css but all examples I found are not styled in internet explorer 11 where slider looks like so:

[image]

Do you know how to style it and why only ie 11 show no style when defined?

Comment: the good thing is IE11 support this `range slider` effect. but other browser like chrome or Firefox are far behind to implementing this effect..

Comment: you should check this link then. but its work only on IE11.  http://jsbin.com/xijudeme/1/edit

Answer (score 20, accepted):

IE11 gives you a few pseudo elements related to the `range` input, which you can read about [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869604%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

1. `::-ms-fill-lower` controls styling of the sliders track before the slider thumb
2. `::-ms-fill-upper` same as above, but after the thumb
3. `::-ms-thumb` - for the slider thumb itself.
4. `::-ms-tooltip` - controls styling of the tooltip of a slider
5. `::-ms-track` styles the sliders individual tracks.

An example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8QHwL/3/)

```
::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: coral;
}

::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: peru;
}

::-ms-thumb {
    background: steelblue;
}
```

Comment: Wow I didn't heard about this. I know only IE11 by default provide styling for range input field. any idea how to give look & feel in Firefox and chrome browser?

Comment: Both browsers provide similar pseudo elements (though not as many as IE) - take a look at: http://tjvantoll.com/2013/04/15/list-of-pseudo-elements-to-style-form-controls/#input_range

Comment: My IE 11 seems not to recognize those pseudo elements. Any ideas?

Comment: @gye , Yes I'm facing the same problem. Any live example for IE ?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the 5 pseudo-elements mentioned by **@adrift**, there are 2 more related to ticks. So to recap:

1. `::-ms-fill-lower` controls styling of the sliders track before the slider thumb
2. `::-ms-fill-upper` same as above, but after the thumb
3. `::-ms-thumb` the slider thumb itself.
4. `::-ms-tooltip` controls styling of the tooltip of a slider
5. `::-ms-track` styles the sliders individual tracks
6. `::-ms-ticks-before` styles tick marks that appear before the track
7. `::-ms-ticks-after` styles tick marks that appear after the track

Note that you can have 3 different sets of ticks (!): the track has its own set. Use `color: transparent` to hide.

Comment: To be clear: to hide the ticks, you set `color: transparent;` on `::-ms-track`, not on `::-ms-ticks-before` and `::-ms-ticks-after`

Answer (score 1):

To get these looking as close as possible, I combined some of the answers above.  The only "extra" is that IE has a track fill "upper" and "lower" not available in Fox, Safari, Chrome, and Edge.

```
.slider {
        /* Chrome, Edge */
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }

    .slider:focus {
        /* Eliminates focus on Chrome, Edge */
        outline: none;
    }

    .slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
        /* Chrome, Edge */
        background: rgb(239, 239, 239);
        border: 1px solid rgb(178, 178, 178);
        border-radius: 25px;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 8px;
    }

    .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        /* Chrome, Edge thumb */
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        background: rgb(7, 114, 251);
        border: 0px;
        border-radius: 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 16px;
        margin-top: -5px;
        width: 16px;
    }

    .slider::-moz-range-track {
        /* FF Range track */
        background: rgb(239, 239, 239);
        border: 1px solid rgb(178, 178, 178);
        border-radius: 25px;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 8px;
    }

    .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
        /* FF Range thumb */
        background: rgb(7, 114, 251);
        border: 0px;
        border-radius: 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 16px;
        width: 16px;
    }

    .slider::-ms-track {
        /* IE Range track */
        background: transparent;
        border-color: transparent;
        border-width: 5px 0; /* allows taller thumb */
        color: transparent;
        height: 8px;
    }

    .slider::-ms-thumb {
        /* Thumb */
        background: rgb(7, 114, 251);
        border: 0px;
        border-radius: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        width: 16px;
    }

    .slider::-ms-fill-lower {
        /* IE Range lower fill */
        background: rgb(7, 114, 251);
        border: 1px solid rgb(62, 116, 184);
        border-radius: 50px;
    }

    .slider::-ms-fill-upper {
        /* IE Range upper fill */
        background: rgb(239, 239, 239);
        border: 1px solid rgb(178, 178, 178);
        border-radius: 50px;
    }

    .slider::-ms-tooltip {
        /* IE Range upper fill */
        display:none;
    }
```

Here's the range itself -- note there are two bootstrap classes to remove padding and set width  --

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider p-0 w-100" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a great article about this on medium: https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/

If you already have a build process running, I recommend installing [postcss-input-range](https://github.com/jonathantneal/postcss-input-range) which handles all those prefixes for you.